# How to transform string into binary records?

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have such base [here](https://www.kaggle.com/faizunnabi/autism-screening/version/1#Autism_Data.arff).

```
df = pd.read_csv('c:/1/Autism_Data.arff',na_values="?")
```

[image]

I need to transform columns: "gender", "jundice", "austim" into binar records 0-1.
I would like to see this table like that.
[image]

Comment: can you post the code text output of the table?  It will be easier to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to be brief you can use `pd.Categorical`. For example,

```
df['gender'] = pd.Categorical(df.gender).codes
```

you can extend this to the other desired columns. These will assign the numbers alphabetically - so you ought to pay attention to that and mask otherwise desired results. Alternatively, if you would like some more control you can use [`LabelEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html).

```
sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = LabelEncoder()
df['gender'] = le.fit_transform(df.gender)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Categorical' object has no attribute 'cat'

Comment: @WojciechMoszczyński modified. Its `.codes` although you may like @furas solution better if you want to specify the number explicitly for every column instead of having them automatically made.

Answer (score 1):

You can `map()` values with `df['gender'].map({'f':1, 'm':0})`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'gender':['f','m','m','f', 'f'],
    'jundice':['no','no','yes','no','no'],
    'austim':['no','yes','yes','yes','no'],
})
#print(df)

df['gender'] = df['gender'].map({'f':1, 'm':0})
df['jundice'] = df['jundice'].map({'yes':1, 'no':0})
df['austim'] = df['austim'].map({'yes':1, 'no':0})

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   gender  jundice  austim
0       1        0       0
1       0        0       1
2       0        1       1
3       1        0       1
4       1        0       0
```